How to navigate from tabs screen to stack screen in react native
I am a beginner in mobile app development.
I started the application using the command - npx create-expo-app@latest myapp. This created the folder structure like this -

I think the parenthesis in the tabs folder name is required for convention. In the main _layout.tsx this is the content -
<ThemeProvider value={colorScheme === 'dark' ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}>
      <Stack>
        <Stack.Screen name="(tabs1)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Eligibility" />
      </Stack>
    </ThemeProvider>

And in the inner _layout.tsx file, there is tabs like -
<Tabs screenOptions={{headerShown: true}}>
        <Tabs.Screen name="index" options={{
          headerTitle: "MyApp",
          title: "Home",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
            <TabBarIcon name={focused ? 'home' : 'home-outline'} color={color} />
          ),
        }} />
      </Tabs>

WHen I am running the app, there is one tab in the footer named Home and the contents which are present in index.tsx file. I want to navigate to the file Eligibility which is present outside the tabs folder.
I tried using this inside index.tsx file
const navigation = useNavigation();
navigation.navigate('Eligibility)

and changed the outer _layout.tsx like this -
<ThemeProvider value={colorScheme === 'dark' ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}>
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen name="RootLayout1" options={{ headerShown: false }} component={RootLayout1} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Eligibility" component={Eligibility} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    </ThemeProvider>

The RootLayout1 is the inner _layout.tsx file with the following contents -
export default function RootLayout1() {
  return (
      <Tabs screenOptions={{headerShown: true}}>
        <Tabs.Screen name="index" options={{
          headerTitle: "Volt",
          title: "Home",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
            <TabBarIcon name={focused ? 'home' : 'home-outline'} color={color} />
          ),
        }} />
      </Tabs>
  );
}

but it was giving error in my navigation.navigate method -
Argument of type '[string]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(options: never): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

What am I doing wrong in this?
I have also tried passing {navigation} in props of index.tsx component and then do navigation.navigate('Eligibility) but getting the error - [TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined]
I want to have 3 tabs in my app like - Home, Profile, Scan&Pay
And in Home tab, I want to have basic flows like some form and then on success it should show Eligibility component inside the same Home tab. Also when I press back on this Eligibility component, the form should be opened again in the Home tab only.
Is there any way to handle my use case?

Hi @Saurav Likhar, can you add source code of RootLayout1 in this thread?

@VuPhung Updated the above post.

Sorry but I don't see where is your HomeScreen and I found some convention error in your code. If I'm wrong, please change me:

<Stack>, <Tabs>: what is this? You mean it from const Stack = createStackNavigator(); and const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();. if true, it is syntax error.
name="(tabs1)", name="index": Please don't define the name of screen/stack/... like that. You need this name for navigate action.

I have a small demo for your case in my snack.
Link Snack: https://snack.expo.dev/@pqv2210/q-78491927.
Please check it.
And if you have any question, drop in comment of this answer.
Welcome to React Native and Happy coding!

Great, Everything looks fine ans as per my need. Just a small change. Can the Eligibility screen be inside the Home tab only? I mean when I press the button in home screen to navigate to eligibility screen, the bottom tabs should still be shown. And when I press the back button in eligibility screen, it should navigate to previous page of Home tab.
@VuPhung

@SauravLikhar yes, it's possible, you need define Eligibility in HomeStack and remove defined Eligibility in RootNavigation.
